# Getting an invalid syntax <Unknown, line 6> error for print function w/ Pylint on VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, pylint

For my weekly course assignment, we're tasked w/ creating simple user entry points for a fictional employee. I ran the code once and everything worked out as I needed it to w/ it asking the user to input data, once input it presented it w/ a title. I forgot to add a field for the employeeName and the "----" lines, so I added all of that in, copy and pasting some of it to get done as the code is highly similar. I then got the syntax error. I checked my spelling for print, deleted the print function, and then used VS Code intellisense to autofill the function, no changes to the error, went through the line to see if I forgot something or added extra nonsense. I looked through similar posts, but they aren't quite getting at my specific issue from what I can tell. Any help is much appreciated.

Regards

```
# user input for an employee's SSN
print("Please enter your SSN #:", end=' ')
employeeSSN = input(str())
print('SSN:', employeeSSN)

print("PLease enter your SSN #:", end=' ')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected results should print the string inside quotations and allow for user input.

Comment: Is that all the code ?

Comment: post also the lines before taht. sometimes the error is on the previous line. Current line is OK

Comment: I dont see no error, although you ignored to ask for the input at he next print statement

Answer (score 0):

I found my own error after some more checking and testing. I forgot to put in an ending parenthesis for line 4 of my code. I found it by taking away the last set of things I worked on and retesting to a good point, then slowly re-adding in the rest. I noticed the missing parenthesis in that process. I wish the error would have pointed my towards that missing part in line 4 then on line 6 and the function. Had me thinking something totally different.

**Example of code mess-up**

```
print("----------------------------", employeeName, "----------------------------"
```

**How I fixed it**

```
print("----------------------------", employeeName, "----------------------------")
```

Sometimes, its the simplest things right in our face. Hopefully this helps someone else.